# Vuejs get component HTML and send it via ajax POST

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to send email with HTML body, but I don't have access to server code, I can only send the email content via ajax.
The server already has API to send email.

I have the component `invoiceEmail` rendered on the fly.

```
sendEmail () {
    const mailConfig = {
        to      : 'johndoe@example.com',
        subject : 'Your Invoice',
        // body    : this.$refs.invoiceEmail.$el, // this doesn't work
        // I'm getting error "converting circular structure to json"
        body    : '<strong style="color:red;">red bold</strong>', // this works
    }
    this.$api.POST('send-email', mailConfig)
        .then(response => {})
        .catch(error => {})
        .finally(() => {})
    },
}
```

If I fill `body` with HTML as string: `'<strong>this should be bold</strong>'`, it works as expected. So if I can just get the HTML, I'm sure the code will work.

This is `console.log(this.$refs.invoiceEmail.$el)`

[image]

What should I use to get the plain HTML instead of `this.$refs.invoiceEmail.$el` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `this.$refs.yourRef.$el.innerHTML` which returns you the inner HTML as a string.

Also just to expand this answer a little bit: `this.$refs.yourRef.$el` returns a raw DOM object, just as you would have as if you'd do `document.getElementById('myelement')` with raw Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

Try parsing it like so  `this.$refs.invoiceEmail.$el.toString()`. *this will not work*

@Flame is correct, `.innerHTML` will work.

Comment: The error is gone, but I only get [object HTMLDivElement] in the email